# Using Mercurial to merge specific hunks of code

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging

Using Mercurial on a repo with several branches, is there a way to update a branch with only specific code from the main trunk?

For example, if we focus on 1 file that exists in both the branch and the trunk. This file is similar in both the branch and the trunk except for one line of code.

If changes are made in the main trunk file, is there a way to pull these changes in to the trunk without performing a full merge (i.e. I still want to keep the branch and trunk separate, I just want to update the branch with some of the trunk changes without having to manually copy/paste those changes in to the branch)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [hg graft](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/graft) command:

> hg graft [OPTION]... [-r] REV...
>
> copy changes from other branches onto the current branch
>
> This command uses Mercurial's merge logic to copy individual changes
>   from other branches without merging branches in the history graph.
>   This is sometimes known as 'backporting' or 'cherry-picking'. By
>   default, graft will copy user, date, and description from the source
>   changesets.
>
> Changesets that are ancestors of the current revision, that have
>   already been grafted, or that are merges will be skipped.
>
> If --log is specified, log messages will have a comment appended of
>   the form:
>
> (grafted from CHANGESETHASH)
>
> If a graft merge results in conflicts, the graft process is
>   interrupted so that the current merge can be manually resolved. Once
>   all conflicts are addressed, the graft process can be continued with
>   the -c/--continue option.